# How do I prevent a form from double-posting when using jquery serialize and formvalidation.io?

Tags: jquery, post, serialization, formvalidation.io

I use the formvalidation.io library for validating data in scripts. It works perfectly when doing a normal page submit but when I opt to use jquery and serialize to submit it posts twice. This can be seen in weblogs as well as 2 emails sent upon submit. If I comment out the formvalidation from the javascript it posts once. I have tried reorganizing and rearranging the javascript to no avail.  The relevant code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* FORM-VALIDATION */
  $('#ContactForm').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    icon: {
      valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
      invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
      validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
      'fname': {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'The first name is required'
          },
          stringLength: {
            min: 2,
            max: 40,
            message: 'First name must be at least 2 characters long'
          }
        }
      },
      'lname': {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'The last name is required'
          },
          stringLength: {
            min: 2,
            max: 40,
            message: 'First name must be at least 2 characters long'
          }
        }
      },
      'email': {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'The email address is required'
          },
          emailAddress: {
            message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
          }
        }
      },
      'message': {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Message text is required'
          },
          stringLength: {
            min: 10,
            max: 1000,
            message: 'Your message must be between 10 and 1000 characters in length.'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
  /* FORM-VALIDATION */

  /* SERIALIZE & SUBMIT FORM */
  $(function() {
    var form = $('#ContactForm');
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var formData = $(form).serialize();
      $("#Result").html( "" );
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData,
        success: function(html) { $("#Result").html( html ); }
      });
    });
  });
  /* SERIALIZE & SUBMIT FORM */

});
```

You can view a live demo at: http://www.dottedi.biz/demo/code/public/serialize+formvalidation/

Answer (score 0):

I changed the SERIALIZE code to the following and it is now working:

```
/* SERIALIZE & SUBMIT FORM */
.on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
  var form = $('#ContactForm');
  var formMessages = $('#form-messages');
  $(form).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(form).serialize();
    $("#Result").html( "" );
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: $(form).attr('action'),
      data: formData,
      success: function(html) { $("#Result").html( html ); }
    });
  });
});
/* SERIALIZE & SUBMIT FORM */
```